# How can I declare a PropType corresponding to a nullable number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm looking for a `PropType` that means

> "this is required, and it will either be a number or be null"

In other words, what I have now is

```
PropTypes.number.isRequired
```

but that throws a warning if a `null` value gets passed in, yet I want `null` to be an acceptable value.

Comment: Could you clarify that you want a warning thrown when the prop is passed `undefined` but are fine with `null` (i.e., to detect a typo)?

Comment: This seems to be the latest on this, since I've been following it. https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/pull/90

Answer (score 63):

Just use:

```
PropTypes.number
```

By default all prop types aren't required (i.e. allow `null` *or* `undefined`) unless you pop a `.isRequired` on the end of them.

You can see the full docs for proptypes here:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: But this allows `undefined` too, which allows forgetting to set the prop!

Comment: Good to be aware of, but probably satisfies the OP's requirements still.

Answer (score 34):

You simply could use:

> `PropTypes.number`

and in defaultProps:

> `yourPropName: null`

Answer (score 8):

Currently `prop-types` library don't allow this. The way i get around this is using a custom validation function

```js
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  nullableArray: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    const { propName: data } = props;

    if (data === undefined) {
      return new Error(`Undefined ${propName} is not allowed`);
    }

    if (data !== null) {
      return; //this is allow when data is loading
    }

    if (!_.isArray(data)) {
      return new Error(`${propName} must be an array`);
    }
  }
};
```

You can make another step further to create a high order function to generate the validation function. this should get you started

```js
generateRequiredOrNullValidationFunction = expectedType => {
  if (expectedType !== "array") {
    return Error(`Unexpected ${expectedType}`);
  }

  return function(props, propName, componentName) {
    const { [propName]: data } = props;

    if (data === undefined) {
      return new Error(`Undefined ${propName} is not allowed`);
    }

    if (data !== null) {
      return; //this is allow when data is loading
    }

    if (expectedType === "array" && !_.isArray(data)) {
      return new Error(`${propName} must be an array`);
    }
  };
};
```

In this snippet, `expectedType` is a enumeration such as `bool` , `array`, `number` ...

Comment: You could use a `TypeError` instead of a generic `Error`. How would you use the snippet `generateRequiredOrNullValidationFunction`?

Answer (score 3):

To help with this quite common issue, I created a clean and fully-typed wrapper called [better-prop-types](https://github.com/ivangabriele/better-prop-types):

```js
import BetterPropTypes from 'better-prop-types'

// ...

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  aProp: BetterPropTypes.string.isRequiredButNullable,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import propTypes from 'prop-types';

const nullable = propType => (props, propName, ...rest) =>
  props[propName] === null ? null : propType(props, propName, ...rest);

const testMe = {
  a: 'string',
  b: 420,
  c: null,
  d: undefined,
  e: undefined
};

const testSchema = {
  a: nullable(propTypes.string.isRequired),
  b: nullable(propTypes.string.isRequired),
  c: nullable(propTypes.number.isRequired),
  d: nullable(propTypes.bool.isRequired),
  e: nullable(propTypes.number)
};

propTypes.checkPropTypes(testSchema, testMe, 'prop', 'testMe');
// Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `b` of type `number` supplied to `testMe`, expected `string`.
// Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `d` is marked as required in `testMe`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

Comment: Best answer here! If anyone's having trouble figuring out the usage: just wrap your `.isRequired` proptypes validator in `nullable(...)`. It works as a very simple custom validator and it works because if the value to be validated is null, it'll just abort the validation before it even sees the `isRequired`, and therefore won't throw an error.

Comment: I've downvoted because you've left a code only answer which not helpful for understanding the 'why' behind what you wrote.

Comment: What is the difference between `propTypes` (with minor p) and `PropTypes` (with capital P) which I'm using? Am I wrong or do line 3-4 just create an infinite loop  if it isn't null? Can @user help?

Comment: Not sure why you pinged me but... `import propTypes from ...` and `import PropTypes from...` are the same, just preference really (when you import a default import you can call it anything, `import pANcAKES from 'prop-types'` would work the same). Internally, within `prop-types`'s code, they capitalise it, so some people follow that, but also there's a convention to only capitalise classes, types and React components, so 

Comment: And it's not infinite recursion because it doesn't call itself, it (conditionally) calls the function that is passed in. e.g. in `nullable(propTypes.number)`, it creates and returns a function (the `(props, ...) =>` bit) that calls the previously-provided `propType` function (here, `propTypes.number`) only if the passed in prop isn't null

Answer (score 0):

Yup just add

```
Component.propTypes = {
  numberAttribute: PropTypes.number
}
```

By default it will have `undefined` value. But you can chage default value to null or any number.

```
EventLeaderboardPage.defaultProps = {
  numberAttribute: null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

###### This should be possible using:

```js
Component.propTypes = {
  numberTypeProp: PropTypes.oneOfType([() => null, PropTypes.number])
}
```

This should mean that the prop(`numberTypeProp`) accepts a `number` or `null` value