# How to specify null prop type in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null, nullable, immutable.js

I've got a prop on a ReactJS Component that's either null or an Immutable Map.

At the bottom of my widget if I write:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
    myMap: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.Map)
};
```

I am leaving this open to the possibility of being null, undefined, or a Map.

How can I make this required and of type null or map only?

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

I see this example but I do not know how to tailor the syntax to my needs or if it is even possible.

Edit:
If a property is null, then it is still there but undefined means that it's not been included altogether.

For example:

```
<Component id={1} data={null} />
<Component id={2} data={Immutable.Map()} />
<Component id={3} />
```

Comment: What's the difference you see in a property not being there or it being null?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I declare a PropType corresponding to a nullable number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37842868/how-can-i-declare-a-proptype-corresponding-to-a-nullable-number)

Comment: A possible solution is under discussion here https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/pull/90, adding a `isDefined()` and a `isNotNull()`

Answer (score 22):

It is possible to use `PropTypes.oneOf([null]).isRequired`. It should allow null, and nothing else. You can combine that with any other type:

```
PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  PropTypes.oneOf([null]).isRequired,
]).isRequired
```

**Edit:** I just had this prop type fail for me when given a null prop using prop-types 15.7.2, so I'm not sure this works anymore (if it ever did?). I reverted to allowing both undefineds and nulls by just not using isRequired.

Comment: This worked for me using numbers in create react app > react-scripts 3.4.1

Comment: worked for me only without the `.isRequired `

Answer (score 14):

I had similar problem and that's how I got here. I found a solution that's good enough for me, so I might as well share it.

In short, I removed `.isRequired` and set `defaultProps` to `null`.

I wanted something like this:

```
// this won't work, because `PropTypes.null` doesn't exists!
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  item: PropTypes.oneOfType([ItemPropTypesShape, PropTypes.null]).isRequired,
};

// this also won't work!
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  item: PropTypes.oneOfType([ItemPropTypesShape, PropTypes.instanceOf(null)]).isRequired,
};
```

The null is always treated as error when prop is required.

I ended up doing this:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  item: ItemPropTypesShape,
};

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  item: null,
};
```

If PropTypes is all we have, this works for me!

Answer (score 11):

This requirement seems to be unsupported with the current version of React.

Refer to [React issue #2166](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2166) for more details. This issue discusses the possibility of an `isRequiredOrNull` property in addition to `isRequired`. [Bottom line](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2166#issuecomment-169143702):

> I wouldn't expect there to be further changes to PropTypes. Flow has become much more mature recently, and from what I heard from the React team, it is the longer term solution to type checking. This puts PropTypes into the same "compatibility" bucket in terms of priorities—like createClass or React addons, they are still supported, but only with bugfixes and performance improvements, without adding new features or changing the API.

In other words, **if you require more sophisticated type checking, use [Flow](https://flowtype.org/) instead**.

Comment: In 2021, Flow is on the way out in favor of TypeScript.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like `PropTypes.instanceOf(null)` works.

- react@16.8
- prop-types@15.6

Comment: `TS2345: Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new (...args: any[]) => {}'.`

Comment: Warning: Failed prop type: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
Doesn't work on React 16.8 with prop-types 15.7 so I'm doubting this on 15.6

Answer (score 3):

You can use the prop type without `.isRequired`.

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string
}
```

And define the `null` value in the `defaultProps`

```
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
    name: null
}
```

Comment: You made a mistake in second snippet, remove propTypes to defaultProps

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late but this work for me, is a custom propType. More info in react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes

```
static propTypes = {
  myMap: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    if (props[propName] !== null && !(props[propName] instanceof Immutable.Map)) {
      return new Error(
        'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to `' + componentName + '`. Expected null or Immutable.Map, but received ' + typeof props[propName] + '. Validation failed.'
      )
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To help with this quite common issue, I created a clean and fully-typed wrapper called [better-prop-types](https://github.com/ivangabriele/better-prop-types):

```js
import BetterPropTypes from 'better-prop-types'

// ...

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  myMap: BetterPropTypes.PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.Map).isRequiredButNullable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
PropTypes.shape({ current: PropTypes.object })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.