# React proptype array of objects with possibly missing properties

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a prop that is surely an array of objects. The objects can or cannot have a number of properties like this.

```
columns: [
    {name: 'name'  //is always required  }, 
    {name: 'security_group_rules'   , display: "Rules" },
    {name: 'revision_number'        , display: "revision number" , sortable:true },
]
```

How can I write the object part to validate the properties to be either a value or undefined

I thought about writing it in this way but it looks odd

```
columns         : PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
       name     : PropType.string.isRequired,
       display  : PropTypes.oneOfType ([PropType.string, undefined])
       sortable : PropTypes.oneOfType ([PropType.bool, undefined])
  })
).isRequired
```

Answer (score 0):

This question looks similar with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37842868/how-can-i-declare-a-proptype-corresponding-to-a-nullable-number). Take a look.

You can apply defaultProps on those optional properties.

```
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
    columns: [{
        display: undefined,
        sortable: undefined
    }];
};

MyComponent.propTypes = {
    columns: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
            name: PropType.string.isRequired,
            display: PropType.string,
            sortable: PropType.bool
        })
    ).isRequired,
    ...
}
```