# Proptypes that allows array or null

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a prop that received an array of string or null value, how to specify a react propType for that prop?

i.e.,

```
myprop = ["hello"]
myprop = null
```

are allowed for prop value

I tried

```
prop: PropTypes.oneOfType([
                [null],
                PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)])
```

this syntax doesn't seem to be allowed.

Comment: Maybe just use `PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)` and it will be optional by default, so `null` will also be allowed

Comment: You can read more about null props on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37842868/how-can-i-declare-a-proptype-corresponding-to-a-nullable-number

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
prop: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)])
```

By default, all prop types aren't required (i.e. allow null or undefined) unless you pop a .isRequired on the end of them.